# validity period (x years) for code signing certificate, what does it mean?

Tags: certificate, code-signing

I want to purchase a code signing certificate, but unsure about the expiration or validity period. Suppose I buy a 2-year certificate, does that mean..

- (a) after 2 years, I can no longer sign new executables with it (but any existing signed executables remain considered 'secure')

or

- (b) after 2 years, my previously signed executables are no longer considered 'secure' and I'd have to create new ones

or both?

Answer (score 1):

Meaning of validity is (a) as per your post. But not entirely (a), the signed executables will be considered signed till eternity only if you timestamp them while signing.

So, if you purchase the code signing certificate on Jan 1st 2013, it will expire on 31st Dec. 2013. 
You can sign as many exe's as you want during this period. But after 31st Dec. you will not be able to sign an exe using it (unless renewed).

However, during signing if you specify the timestamp, then the exe's you have signed and distributed will continue to remain signed till end of time.

References:

1. [blog article](http://gunsh.com/blog/2011/02/02/authenticode-signature-becomes-invalid-after-certificate-expires/)
2. [verisign kb](https://knowledge.verisign.com/support/ssl-certificates-support/index?page=content&id=SO15544)